# VS code SCM and Explorer not showing the green color , U , M keywords related to Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, project

For my project , I installed Git . and entered git init actually to the parent folder.then suddenly all my files in Project explorer Tabs changed to green color. So to undo it i entered this cmd `rm -rf .git` in my terminal.
So after refreshing the green color went away, Then I went to my project folder and then typed `git init` it created a repository but the green color in file explorer is not showing .

Even I edit SCM section , It is not showing any changes or commits .

Please provide solution for making these green indicators to be visible

I was expecting to get the green color indication on my explorer.

Comment: Is your setting `SCM: Diff Decorations` enabled?

Comment: yes , it enabled

Comment: I am also having this issue